Azure Function - MySQL EFCore certifcate in connection string
I want to verify and use a certificate (PEM file) from Azure MySQL Server. I need to be able to add this to KV and then use it in my connection string.

So I download this certificate and then i want to put it in my key vault and access it in my Azure function for the connection string for EfCore (pomelo).
I get this error in Keyvault and it makes sense to me but how do i get the private key so i can add it in ?
Private key is not specified in the specified X.509 PEM certificate content. Please specify private key in the X.509 PEM certificate content.

My PEM certificate i have downloaded from the MySQL Pane in Azure just gives me
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blah
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

and i need the private key inside it too like it shows in the azure documentation :
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
I need to do a full verify of the certificate in my connection string like this :
Server=**=dbheat;Uid=**;Pwd=**;SslMode=VerifyCA;SslCert='/'",


To obtain the private key from your PEM certificate, you will need to have access to the original certificate request that was used to generate the certificate. The private key is typically generated and stored on the server where the certificate request was made. If you do not have access to the original certificate request and private key, you will need to generate a new certificate request and obtain a new certificate with a private key.

Once you have the private key, you can add it to your Key Vault along with the certificate. To use the certificate and private key in your connection string for EFCore, you can reference the certificate and private key by their respective paths in Key Vault.

Here is an example connection string that uses a certificate and private key from Key Vault:
Server=myserver.mysql.database.azure.com;Database=mydatabase;Uid=myusername;Pwd=mypassword;CertificateFile=/path/to/cert.pem;PrivateKeyFile=/path/to/key.pem;SslMode=VerifyFull;
Note that the CertificateFile and PrivateKeyFile parameters reference the paths to the certificate and private key in Key Vault.
